# Loading 3D model along with 3D terrain on Mapbox

Tags: next.js, three.js, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl

I am trying to add a 3D model as a custom layer on Mapbox using Three.js. I also want to add a 3D terrain on the map. I followed the individual examples to add a [3D model](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model/) and [3D terrain](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-terrain/) from Mapbox.

The problem I am facing is that the 3D model is appearing for a second till the terrain loads and then disappears once the terrain completes loading. If I only load the model, it is displaying properly.

This loadTerrain() function gets called on load of the map that then calls the loadModel() function:

```
async function loadTerrain() {
    mapRef.current?.getMap().addSource("mapbox-dem", {
      type: "raster-dem",
      url: "mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-terrain-dem-v1",
      tileSize: 512,
    });

    mapRef.current
      ?.getMap()
      .setTerrain({ source: "mapbox-dem", exaggeration: 1.5 });

    loadModel();
 }
```

```
function loadModel(fragGroup: any) {
    const modelOrigin: [number, number] = [76.9558, 11.0168];
    const modelAltitude = 0;
    const modelRotate = [Math.PI / 2, 0, 0];

    const modelAsMercatorCoordinate = MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat(
      modelOrigin,
      modelAltitude
    );

    const modelTransform = {
      translateX: modelAsMercatorCoordinate.x,
      translateY: modelAsMercatorCoordinate.y,
      translateZ: modelAsMercatorCoordinate.z,
      rotateX: modelRotate[0],
      rotateY: modelRotate[1],
      rotateZ: modelRotate[2],
      scale: modelAsMercatorCoordinate.meterInMercatorCoordinateUnits(),
    };

    const customLayer: any = {
      id: "3d-model",
      type: "custom",
      renderingMode: "3d",
      layout: {
        visibility: "visible",
      },
      onAdd: function (map: any, gl: any) {
        this.camera = new THREE.Camera();
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

        const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
        directionalLight.position.set(0, -70, 100).normalize();
        this.scene.add(directionalLight);

        const directionalLight2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
        directionalLight2.position.set(0, 70, 100).normalize();
        this.scene.add(directionalLight2);

        const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
        loader.load(
          "https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/34M_17/34M_17.gltf",
          (gltf) => {
            this.scene.add(gltf.scene);
          }
        );

        this.map = map;

        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
          canvas: map.getCanvas(),
          context: gl,
          antialias: true,
        });

        this.renderer.autoClear = false;
      },
      render: function (gl: any, matrix: any) {
        const rotationX = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(
          new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0),
          modelTransform.rotateX
        );
        const rotationY = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(
          new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0),
          modelTransform.rotateY
        );
        const rotationZ = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(
          new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1),
          modelTransform.rotateZ
        );

        const m = new THREE.Matrix4().fromArray(matrix);
        const l = new THREE.Matrix4()
          .makeTranslation(
            modelTransform.translateX,
            modelTransform.translateY,
            modelTransform.translateZ
          )
          .scale(
            new THREE.Vector3(
              modelTransform.scale,
              -modelTransform.scale,
              modelTransform.scale
            )
          )
          .multiply(rotationX)
          .multiply(rotationY)
          .multiply(rotationZ);

        this.camera.projectionMatrix = m.multiply(l);
        this.renderer.resetState();
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
        this.map.triggerRepaint();
      },
    };

    mapRef.current?.getMap().addLayer(customLayer);
}
```

I am using react-map-gl to render the mapbox map on a Next.js application.

I am expecting to load the model and terrain together but my model is getting disappeared as soon as terrain gets loading.

Answer (score 0):

Using the standard example, you will need to recalculate the projection Matrix using the elevation of the anchor point once the terrain layer is loaded.

Maybe you want to take a look to [Threebox Camera projection](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox/blob/2cdbd1f17865eef86c6cdeb0d4677029aac5b3d6/src/camera/CameraSync.js#L119C1-L122C57).

```js
// When terrain layers are included, height of 3D layers must be modified from t_camera.z * worldSize
if (t.elevation) cameraWorldMatrix.elements[14] = t._camera.position[2] * worldSize;
//this.camera.matrixWorld.elements is equivalent to t._camera._transform
this.camera.matrixWorld.copy(cameraWorldMatrix);
```

there's an specific [example positioning a 3D model over terrain](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox/tree/master/examples) with the Glacier d'Argentiere. I'm maintaining this repo since 4 years ago and it has been included as an [official example in Mapbox](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model-threebox/).
[image]

Hope it helps!